# Changing the orientation of app flickers for few seconds

Tags: cordova, device-orientation

I have created a responsive phonegap app to support both portrait and landscape orientations.  It works perfectly, however *unlike native app the full dimension app is not rotating* instead ***it shows half the screen and after a few seconds it cover the whole landscape view*** and vice versa for portrait view.

[image]

Can someone suggest your views to fix this issue?

Comment: There is very little one can do in this regard, especially if there are a large number DOM elements that must be recalculated. You *can* try and mitigate this somewhat by relying on media queries for orientation instead of JavaScript -- the media queries are handled well in advance of JavaScript being notified of the rotation. Without knowing more about how you're intercepting the orientation change, that's about all I can say.

Answer (score 0):

it will never work like native app, although "few seconds" seems very long, maybe you have there too big images or something.

Comment: I don't have big images. `will never work like native app` I'm afraid of this sentence.  However I feel someone must have fixed it.  Let us wait for their solution, cheers.

Comment: for start, it would be good if you would tell us which UI framework are you using, if you do. if not, show some code, css orso.

Comment: I don't think this as a css behavior in my app.  But could be happened with UI framework and I am using [foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Comment: I used Intel's XDK (appramework ui) and my app is experiencing about <1s of such behavior also. I really dont think you can get rid of this effect, this is webview issue, if you will open some website in e.g. chrome on your phone, you will see that same thing happens.