# White flickering on cordova app orientation change

Tags: cordova

is it possible to change the color of the background in the parts of the screen that reveals when the device is rotated? Currently I cannot understand what color is used, somewhere it's white and somewhere it is gray.
Tried to set the body and html background as well as config.xml "backgroundColor" preference, but with no success.

Please help.

Found the same question here, but it is 2 years old. No news yet?
[Changing the orientation of app flickers for few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344353/changing-the-orientation-of-app-flickers-for-few-seconds)

Comment: Same problem here. It is not the same question as the one pointed in Community's edit. It's only a question of color, anything else. Delays and sizes are well.